# Cypress: how to wait for all requests to be finished

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want  to wait all api requests  to be finished and only after that perform actions (click on buttons, type something etc.) The code below is not working and 'somelocator' is being clicked before all requests are fully loaded.

```
cy.intercept('/**').as("allapirequests")
cy.wait("@allapirequests")
cy.get('somelocator').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

first parameter of intercept should be a method, try some like:

```
cy.intercept({ method: "GET", url: "**/", }).as("allapirequests");
cy.wait("@allapirequests");
cy.get('locator').should("exist").click({ force: true });
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to wait all POST and GET requests altogether. And also cy.wait waits only first alias request but not an array of requests